# IntelliJ IDEA LiveReload not working when external changes

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, webstorm, livereload, hotswap

Is it possible to enable LiveReload of static files in IntelliJ IDEA community which are changed from external tool like WebStorm?

**Context:**

I use IntelliJ to run Spring web app with frontend static files and WebStorm to modify them. My issue is that every time I make change in WebStorm, I have to focus to IntelliJ window and only then I'm able to see these changes in browser.

Comment: No; when changes are made externally, IDEA becomes aware of the change when it's virtual file system is synchronized with external changes only - i.e. on switching focus/choosing **File | Synchronize**